# What is the simplest way to create source Debian package?

Tags: package, deb, checkinstall

Suppose you have hello.c

```
int main() { return 0; }
```

and Makefile

```
hello: hello.c
        gcc hello.c -o hello

install: hello
        install -m 755 hello /usr/bin/
```

The quickest and easiest way to get binary package seems to be to use checkinstall:

```
fakeroot checkinstall --pkgname hello -y -D --install=no --backup --nodoc --fstrans --pkgversion 0.0.1 make install
```

How to do similar thing, but for source package (to put it to some source repository or use "dpkg-buildpackage" on it)?

[The officicial text](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html) is rather long: orig.tar.gz, changelog, control file...   Is there something like checkinstall, but for source packages? Additional bonus whould be if it also figures out dependencies automatically (at least partially).

Comment: `dh-make` comes to mind, but it does require some manual work.  It's not like a tool could create the package description in `debian/control` for you anyway.  It doesn't check dependencies but there are separate tools for that.